# Which directory does clickonce publish?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

When I am using clickonce, which files are published?

The ones from the bin or the obj directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything inside the obj directory is intermediate build artefacts, which can safely be discarded at any time.

Anything in the bin folder is the final result from the whole build process.

ClickOnce by default publishes all final build artefacts, with the exception of the symbols file. You can change what is published from the Publish tab in the project properties.